# What is the differencen of 'imread' in Matlab and 'cv.imread' in OpneCV?

Tags: matlab

I read a 'lable.png' file with unit8 format using 'imread' in Matlab and cv.imread in OpneCV, but the result is different.

In specific, the result of cv.imread is correct, but the result of 'imread' in Matlab converts the actual 255 to 0, which is wrong.

Here is the code:

matlab:

```
map = imread('label.png')
```

python:

```
map = cv2.imread('label.png')
```

I want to know why it happens and how to read the right value using Matlab?

Comment: have you tried plotting the matrix you get with imread in matlab? maybe the image is just flipped

Comment: Yes, I use imagesc function to show  the matrix, and the 255 is changed to 0. Furthermore, I use `max(map(:))` to see the max value of the matrix I got in matlab, it is not 255.

Answer (score 0):

If I read in a png image with imread in matlab, my values range from 0 to 255 (black is 0 in all channels). Maybe in your case, the function is inferring the format of your content wrong. Try stating the format directly:

```
m = imread('image.png', 'png');
```

Comment: I have tried it and failed, and I solved this probelm by using the followed solution, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, the problem is solved by:

```
map=imread('image.png','BackgroundColor','none')
```